# Copy the structure of a pytable table

Tags: python, pytables

I am trying to create a new table based on the structure of an existing table. I am using the following code:

```
desc = hf.root,my_table1.description._v_colobjects.copy()
desc['new_col1'] = tables.StringCol(12)
...
hf.createTable('/','mytable2', desc)
```

Is this the right way of doing things? I am not sure if I can directly access _v_colobjects.

Comment: Are you just trying to copy the description or are you trying to add to the description?

Comment: Copy the description, add/remove/modify, and then use the new description to create new tables.

Comment: It should work. You should be able to access the objects. Just need to convert `hf.root,my_table1.description._v_colobjects.copy()` to `hf.root.my_table1.description._v_colobjects.copy()`